# Improving the performance of this select query

Tags: performance, select, oracle-10g

i have two tables  TABLE 1 and TABLE 2

And i am running this `select` query to fetch the data , it takes long time to run

```
SELECT TABLE1.* , TABLE2.COL1 , TABLE2.COL4 FROM TABLE1, TABLE2     
WHERE TABLE1.COL1 IN('1','TEXT','HO TED')     
AND TABLE1.COL2= 1800 AND TABLE2.COL1 = 10519198     
AND TABLE1.COL3>= 100 AND TABLE1.COL4= TABLE2.col2
AND TABLE2.COL3=('TEXT')
```

Any suggestions ? so that i could improve performance of this select query .

Does too many `AND` affects my performance ?

Thanks in advance